# How was Butch "conditioned"?

Tags: dc, batman, gotham

In the episode *Scarification* (S02E05), Penguin mentions that Butch has been "conditioned", and is unable to refuse any order Penguin gives him.

> Your conditioning is still working nicely, hmm? (snickers) You can't refuse me.

**When, and how was Butch "conditioned" to the point that he is unable to defy Penguin?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He was "reprogrammed" by Victor Zsasz. Until middle of first season he was loyal to Fish but he was captured and tortured by Victor Zsasz on Penguin orders and therefore became loyal to Penguin. We can see his inner struggle at season finale when Penguin and Fish fought and he couldn't take sides. But since Penguin won and Fish was out of picture he remain loyal to him

Comment: Can you cite an episode, or explain how just torturing him made him loyal to the point that he is unable to defy him? Torturing someone is great for short-term results, but does not typically breed unconditional loyalty.

Comment: It was never shown or explained how he tortured him but in episode 13 of season 1 Butch helped Fish escape Zsasz and his henchwomen and than getting shot in knee. Last scene was Zsasz standing over Butch. Next time we saw him he was reformed

Comment: This being Zsasz it can assumed to involve a knife or two

Comment: One correction: he wasn't reprogrammed on Penguin's orders but on Falcone's orders.  @IG_42 in the first season Zsasz doesn't use knives all that much which is odd for the character.

Comment: Having only really seen him in the Arkham games i found it odd enough that he was fully clothed and capable of holding a conversation

Comment: Right, Falcone was still in the story than... totally forgot about that... IG_42 he doesn't speak much in Gotham ether to be honest, a lot of crazy stares tho XD

Comment: @IG_42 he still cuts himself though... that is shown.